# Where to save configuration/data files on GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, gnu

I have found out, that I can execute my own programs easily by moving them into the /bin file. But I also have seen, that a lot of programs there only consist of one single file that does one simple task and dont needs to save anything in a file.

If I want to write a command line program that also needs to save it's values in a file (for example a little text based game that stores the progress of the player) where the program should store it's data?

There are several dedicated locations in Linux. I want to find out which location is most suitable for, for example, games that need data such as image files and text files and that need to store the progress of the player.

Comment: There's a loooot of places configuration files etc could be saved - `/var`, `/etc`, `~`, `~/.config` etc...

Comment: Which folder should I prefer?

Comment: I believe the standard is to use `~/.config` for user-specific config files, `/var` for config files that get read/written to fairly frequently, and `/etc` for more "static" configs. But this is never set in stone anywhere, you're free to use whichever you'd like. Personally, I'd go for `~/.config` and `/etc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's plenty of places that configuration/data files etc could be saved:

- `~/.config` (config, often instead of `~` as it reduces clutter in the user's home directory).
- `~` (config)
- [`/etc`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/etc.html)
  (config)
- [`/var`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/var.html) (data)
- [`/usr`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html) (data)
- likely many more...

In-depth descriptions of  the purposes of the various subfolders of the top-level directories can be found at the links above.

---

I believe the ad-hoc standard is to use `~/.config` for user-specific config files, `/var` for data files generated during execution, and `/etc` for "static" system-wide configs. `/usr` is used for storing user programs and their static data.

More formal standards do exist - the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) expresses the purpose of the top-level directories, while `~/.config` is the preferred configuration folder for [XDG](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html), and seems to have caught on.

Comment: Ummmm ... no, var is **not** meant for config files.  It stores system-wide logs, cache, status data, things that system processes need to access (even though they may be per user, like e.g. crontabs or mail boxes).  System global config, by definition, lives in `/etc`. User config somewhere in their home, typically `~/.config/` ..

Comment: @tink Thanks for the correction - from [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/var.html), it looks like it can be used for storing data files though, probably where I got this misconception from. I'm editing the answer to reflect this more accurately.

Answer (score 4):

Another suggestion: `~/.local/share` is usually more appropriate for application data that the user should not touch. `~/.config` is typically for user-modifiable configuration.

You should also use the appropriate environment variables, `$XDG_DATA_HOME` for `~/.local/share` and `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` for `~/.config`. Some users like to remap these directories to other locations.